# Attempting to reconnect after a connection was refused - Python

Tags: python, sockets, networking, try-catch

I am trying to create a script that will, on error, attempt to reconnect again. But even after the receiving server has been started it still will not connect

```
send_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
while True:
    try:            #Cant get it to make connection after retrying
        send_sock.connect((ip, port))       #always throws Con Refused when tryed
        break
    except socket.error:
        print "Connection Failed, Retrying.."
        time.sleep(1)
send_sock.send("hi")
```

edit: Corrected "try:" typo

Comment: I'm going to assume that you're using `try:` instead of `Try` in your actual code (because `Try` is not valid syntax)

Comment: I corrected the try statement in the post, Thank you.

Comment: What is the current output?  Does it raise an error?  Does it get to the `send_sock.send` line even though the connection failed?

Comment: are you sure you are connecting to a valid port and ip, i mean is something listening on that port and ip. I tried your code against an app in my machine and its working as expected.

Comment: My ip is localhost and port is 1234. My problem is that if it doesn't connect on first try it won't ever connect. It will keep attempting to connect.

Answer (score 4):

Had this same issue myself, once I had worked it out it was actually quite a simple solution, all you need to do is create the send_sock before every connection attempt. Not sure why this fixes it but it does for me. Hope it does for you too.

```
while True:
    try:#moved this line here
        send_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        send_sock.connect((ip, port)) #no longer throws error
        break
    except socket.error:
        print "Connection Failed, Retrying.."
        time.sleep(1)
    send_sock.send("hi")
```

Comment: You shouldn't add an answer you cannot explain ("Not sure why").

Comment: Yes, because I'm sure there *is* an explanation (and you could find out to make your answer more valuable (for you and for others)).

Comment: I disagree, If you know the answer you should always post it even if you do not know why. Someone else will

Comment: @U.Windl and anyone else wondering why, this is mentioned in the [man page of connect](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/connect.3p.html#APPLICATION_USAGE). The reason is not very satisfying and is simply that the behavior of a failed socket connect in the general case is undefined.  
  
_"If connect() fails, the state of the socket is unspecified. Conforming applications should close the file descriptor and create a new socket before attempting to reconnect."_

Comment: Creating a new connection every time you need to send a message is very resource inefficient. Consider the TCP handshake roundtrips, file descriptor allocation and local TCP port allocation.

Answer (score 0):

Python socket will give you a error that should help with debugging your problem. For your example.

```
try:            
    send_sock.connect((ip, port))       
except socket.error as error:
    print("Connection Failed **BECAUSE:** {}").format(error)
```

Second of all you should almost never use `while true: [...]` as its just going to cause all sorts of problems. In this case you could put in a counter and loop on that break after X attempts.

```
While counter < 100:
      try:            
          send_sock.connect((ip, port))       
       except socket.error as error:
           print("Connection Failed **BECAUSE:** {}").format(error)
           print("Attempt {} of 100").format(counter)
           counter += 1
```

Check out the [Python Docs on socket exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#exceptions) for more info.